# Rails: Ignore specific gem on windows environment or create a :windows group

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, compatibility

We are a team working on a projet. Some work in Ubuntu, some in Mac and some in Windows (pity, I know ...)

Of course, there are compatibility issues between gems.

We managed to fix the most important ones. But some optional ones remain incompatible, like [Railroady](https://github.com/preston/railroady). But then we woud like to be able to keep the line in the gem file, but not being bundled when developping in windows.

`gem 'railroady'`

So I looked for something like this :

```
group :linux, :mac do
  gem 'railroady'
end
```

but I could not find any solution to this. I don't want to add `Gemfile` to `.gitignore` because then we loose compatibility when changing bundle.

Is there a way around to my solution ? We are using Rails 3.2

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by specifying the platforms.

Gems to be installed in Linux/Mac:

```rb
platforms :ruby do
  gem 'railroady'
end
```

Gems to be installed in Windows:

```rb
platforms :mingw do
  gem 'win32console'
end
```

To be sure about your Ruby installation in Windows, you can check out the `RUBY_PLATFORM` constant:

```
ruby -e 'p RUBY_PLATFORM'
```

Which in my case is `"i386-mingw32"`.